# Regex how to match all number pairs, even when nested?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to count all of the number pairs in a text string via regex, even when nested. I would like to have it recognize any number followed by any number.

For example, the input string is Hello1233. Therefore, "12" and "23" and "33" would be identified and the match of number pairs is 3. Using something like \d\d isn't getting the number pair in the middle (the "23") for me.  It captures only 2 matches instead of 3.

In another example, Hello155786, would identify "15" and "55" and "57" and "78" and "86" as matches. \d\d just gets 3 matches instead of the 5 total I am looking for.

How can this be done via Regex to identify all number pairs, even the ones in the middle?

Comment: In what environment?

Comment: Can you please include code to show us what you have tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: A .NET environment. It looks like VS97's python example worked just fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following. I guess you were very close. Here is a Python example, but the idea is the same for any environment:

```
import re

re.findall(r'(?=(\d\d))', 'hello1233')
['12', '23', '33']

re.findall(r'(?=(\d\d))', 'hello155786')
['15', '55', '57', '78', '86']
```

You will need  [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this task, so change your regex from `(\d\d)` to `(?=(\d\d))`.

From documentation:

> (?=...)
>       Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac
>   (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

Comment: From what did you determine that OP is using Python?